# Prove that for any multiplicative arithmetic function $\phi$ we have $\phi(1) = 1$.

Tags: number-theory

Prove that for any multiplicative arithmetic function $\phi$ we have $\phi(1) = 1$.

I know there is a clever way to prove this by it is not coming to mind.

Definition: An arithmetic function $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow C$ is called multiplicative, if $f \neq 0$, and for every two natural numbers $m, n \in \mathbb{N},  \gcd(m, n) = 1$, and 
$f(mn) = f(m)f(n)$.

Comment: Care to define a multiplicative arithmetic function (domain, codomain, properties)?  Why not $\varphi(n) = 0$ for all $n$? That looks multiplicative.

Comment: @KCd I add a definition to the problem

Comment: By definition chasing, $$\phi \not\equiv 0\\
\implies \exists n,\,( \phi(n) \ne 0  )\\
\implies \exists n,\,( \phi(n) \ne 0 \land \gcd(n,1) = 1 )\\
\implies \exists n,\,( \phi(n) \ne 0 \land \phi(n)\phi(1) = \phi(n\cdot1) = \phi(n) )\\
\implies \exists n,\,( \phi(1) = 1 )\\
\implies \phi(1) = 1
$$

Comment: Your definition is seriously flawed! Instead of "gcd$(m,n)=1$, and" you should have "if gcd$(m,n) = 1$, then". Surely you can see the difference?

Answer (score 4):

Usually one requires that $\phi(1)\neq 0$ (for example, see Landau's Lectures). Then $\phi(1)=\phi(1\cdot 1)=\cdots$ does it.

Note that if $\phi(1)=0$, $\phi(n)=0$ for any $n$ since $(n,1)=1$, i.e.$\phi(n)=\phi(1)\phi(n)=0$, so asking $\phi\neq 0$ is the same as asking $\phi(1)\neq 0$, which is equivalent to asking $\phi(1)=1$.