# Let a be an multiplicative arithmetic function. Show: either $a(1) = 1$ or $a(1) = 0$. Show that if $a(1) = 0$ then $a(n) = 0$ for all $n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, arithmetic-functions

I am asked to prove

> Let a be an arithmetic function which is multiplicative. Show that either $a(1) = 1$ or $a(1) = 0$. Show that if $a(1) = 0$ then $a(n) = 0$ for all n.

From definition of arithmetic function, the output of the function is either $0$ or $1$, are there any way that i can actually proving that?

And for the second bit of the question, i tried couple of funtion such as the set of prime number; the set of squares number;
the set of square-free numbers; but anyone can give me some hints of how to prove  if $a(1) = 0$ then $a(n) = 0$ for all n.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that for any multiplicative arithmetic function $\phi$ we have $\phi(1) = 1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838858/prove-that-for-any-multiplicative-arithmetic-function-phi-we-have-phi1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ is such that $f(a\cdot b)=f(a)\cdot f(b)$ if $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.

Let $x = a(1)$, then $$x=a(1)=a(1\cdot 1)=a(1)\cdot a(1)=x^2\implies x\in\{0,1\}$$

If $a(1)=0$ then $$a(n) = a(n)\cdot a(1) =0$$

Comment: Hello Tomas, thank you for upvoting and accepting my answer. Can I ask you please to that tomorrow and not today. So please unaccept and un upvote today and do that tomorrow please.